# Issue with OVH centos custom kernel and network

Tags: ovh

Some of our servers are in OVH. Most of them are installed with Solus but some models of servers does not allow this SO from instalator so

I've just installed :

```
yum install kernel
```

following this guide

http://change_ovh_kernel.onlinephpfunctions.com/

and it boots perfect but I have issue with net card. Server complaints about it

```
eth2 not present, delaying....
```

OVH told me the don't care... But I need install custom kernel to avoid OVH limitations.

Does anyone experience with that?

As I said, I've just installed kernel, modified grub.conf and rebooted. After that, through the java console I can see how Centos boot ok but ... I have the problem with the netword card.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, just quick reply. You need to install latest drivers of ixgbe in your supermicro server and thats all, mine was version 4.1.5 and worked perfect with a OVH supermicro server HOST-32-H - 32G Xeon D-1540